# Bitmap is null reading from file

Tags: android

In my code I am retriving a image from a folder which I have checked contains the image and is not null. For some reason when it gets the the setBitmap code of the wallpaper manager it seems to stop working and output the error below. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

```
                                                                                   Process: coolwallpaper.alexcz.coolwallpaper, PID: 15613
                                                                                    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.graphics.Bitmap.compress(android.graphics.Bitmap$CompressFormat, int, java.io.OutputStream)' on a null object reference
                                                                                        at android.app.WallpaperManager.setBitmap(WallpaperManager.java:956)
                                                                                        at coolwallpaper.alexcz.coolwallpaper.Main$1.onClick(Main.java:54)
                                                                                        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5197)
                                                                                        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20926)
                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5951)
                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
```

---

```
static final File dir = new File("/data/data/coolwallpaper.alexcz.coolwallpaper/app_imageDir/");

    Button createWallpaper;
    Button setWallpaper;

    Bitmap bitmap;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        createWallpaper = (Button)findViewById(R.id.createWallpaper);
        setWallpaper = (Button)findViewById(R.id.set_wallpaper);

        setWallpaper.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (dir.isDirectory()) { // make sure it's a directory
                            for (File f : dir.listFiles()) {
                                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath());
                                System.out.println(bitmap.getWidth());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });

                WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager
                        = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
                try {
                    myWallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        createWallpaper.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Main.this, FractalActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: `bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath());` ?? Why would you execute that statement for all files in that directory? Only the last one would survive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because Async Task runs on a separate Thread. the code ahead of async task which changes the wallpaper, starts executing while bitmap is still being loaded from the file in the background. That's why, setBitmap is being said to contain null argument